# PHPExcel date field does not match source spreadsheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

This is what is in my spreadsheet:

```
12/04/2011  8:56:17 p.m. (xls dateserial = 40645.87242)
```

this is my code I'm using to extract the date and convert to date string in PHP:

```
$txn_date_xls = $sheet->getCell("H$row")->getValue();               
echo "Txn Date (original): $txn_date_xls<br />";

$txn_date = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($txn_date_xls);
echo "Txn Date: ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $txn_date)."<br />";
```

This is the output from my script:

```
Txn Date (original): 40644.55783637732
Txn Date: 2011-04-11 13:23:17
```

The date serial doesn't match the original spreadsheet.
So, I'm trying to determine if this is a bug with PHPExcel or I have missed a setting or something, that I need to do before extracting the dateserial from the cell. Possibly a timezone issue?

Sorry, I'm not very familiar with the PHPExcel library yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not so sure about this but...

Function [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in PHP depends of server's time zone setting.

**PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP()** assumes that the date supplied is GMT and returns the Unix time accordingly.

So try to set GMT/UTC for PHP timezone at the beginning of script (using [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php))

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

or like this (using [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php))

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'UTC');
```

Also, try using [gmdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) instead of [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), otherwise **you may get a 1 day offset**.

Usable link:

- http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: using gmdate() does make a difference, but doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: i saved the same file as an xlsx file and imported it (and used gmdate) and it worked. so maybe it has to do with the file format?

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 - If people advised me of bugs, then I might be in a position to fix them... mostly all I hear is "it doesn't work". But you're right, PHPExcel treats all Excel dateserials as a UTC timestamp. I'm not aware of any value in the .xls BIFF format that would otherwise identify a timezone offset (just the Windows 1900/Mac 1904 calendar switch), while the subsequent use of the date() function to convert the returned unix timestamp value to a display format will adjust for the default timezone.

Comment: I'm not sure what I could do otherwise, converting the Excel dateserial to a local time would introduce a whole slew of problems and complications, so that isn't really a practical option. PS. I was fascinated by your question about the difference in speed of date() with and without a timezone having been set.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 - yeah! sorry 'bout the minor rant. I'm going to have fun trying to isolate bumperbox's original problem... because if PHPExcel is arbitrarily changing the dateserial when reading the xls file, then it could arbitrarily change any float (not just dateserials)... and that would be a mission-critical fail

Comment: @markbarker i am suspect of the source xls file, other ones that i download have worked fine with same code. if it was a bug that i could replicate consistently then i would lodge a report. but giving you something that can't be replicated consistently isn't going to help anyone

Answer (score 2):

Define

```
date_default_timezone_set(YOUR_TIME_ZONE);
```

Change this line:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $txn_date)
```

to:

```
 PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($txn_date_xls, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
```