# Display the data from an array in blockspring spreadsheet using PHP

Tags: php

Hi i have this data which will fetch from the spreadsheet using blockspring API.My problem is how will i able to foreach this one and display the result? Here is my code below

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Check In] => Date(2015,10,20)
                    [Check Out] => Date(2015,10,22)
                    [Confirmation Number] => 1234567
                    [Property] => USJ Midas
                    [Room Number] => 102
                    [Guest Name] => Greg Happy
                    [Guest Email] => ghappy@gmail.com
                )

        )

)

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
echo "</pre>";

foreach($res as $result){
  echo $result->Property;
}
```

Any help is muchly appriciated. TIA

Comment: Uh,  well, it's a multidimensional array, so you'll need to access it like that, `$res['data']` would take you a step inside of the array and your foreach should work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `echo $result->Property;` will end up with a notice, because `->` is an object operator ([objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)), you want to access an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), please try the code below:

```
foreach ( $res["data"] as $result ) {
    echo $result["Property"];
}
```

Due to the comments I've added a solution for the string `Date(2015,10,20)`:

```
foreach ( $res["data"] as $result ) {
    // pattern /[^0-9,]/ removes everything except numbers and the comma
    $checkInString = preg_replace( "/[^0-9,]/" , "", $result["Check In"] );
    $checkOutString = preg_replace( "/[^0-9,]/" , "", $result["Check Out"] );
    // the result of the regex: (i.e.) 2015,10,20, so we create a DateTime object, from the given format Y,m,d
    //
    $checkInDate = DateTime::createFromFormat( "Y,m,d", $checkInString );
    $checkOutDate = DateTime::createFromFormat( "Y,m,d", $checkOutString );

    // call the format method of the DateTime object with the date format we want
    echo $checkInDate->format( "m/d/Y" )."<br>";
    echo $checkOutDate->format( "m/d/Y" )."<br>";
}
```

Comment: how about this date?  [Check In] => Date(2015,10,20) the checkin date in my spreadsheet reads this way 11/18/2015

Comment: can you help me umm the code to get this way?  11/18/2015

Comment: Sorry I was wrong with the date, it is just a simple string, I've updated my answer

Comment: ive tried your code above it seems to work but this is the display
10/20/2015 not 11/18/2015

Comment: it will take the date in from array `=> Date(2015,10,20)` , so I guess you have a row in you spreadsheet with the date 10/20/2015

Comment: that is really strange, maybe the date from the excel file starts with month 0 instead of 1, maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5657758/5297359